# D3.js - Positive and negative bar chart using JSON object data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am extremely new to D3 so please bear with me. I've tried to consult lots of tutorials but think I just need a bit of help to get my head around this.
So I am trying to visualise the impact of COVID on sectors in geographical areas. The information is found in a JSON file which is mapped to a variable `covid'. You can select the county you wish to visualise by doing 'covid.data.____', so to select Aberdeen I have done

```
const aberdeen = covid.data.Aberdeenshire;
```

The data (from console.log(aberdeen) looks like:

[image]

As you can see there are both positive and negative values for the sectors. I want to plot a bar chart which looks something like this, but obviously modified so that the axes only go from +100% to -100%  (image from https://bl.ocks.org/gurjeet/83189e2931d053187eab52887a870c5e):
[image]

The issue is that the example code is using a JSON file, but I want to be able to plot the data from the JSON object as shown. Please can someone help? I've been going round in circles with this one :( Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll need to convert that object into a data array to be able to take advantage of d3's enter/update/exit cycle as D3 is intended to bind one item in the data array to one element in the DOM.

Comment: Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: You can iterate through an object's keys to create an array, or you can use something like `var data = d3.entries(object)`